# Is it possible to implement a score system to my quiz? I want a score out of 5 to be displayed after the quiz is finished

Tags: java

Here is my progress right now. I would really appreciate some assistance. I'm just doing this for practice, but I would really like this program to be as detailed and concise as possible. I am learning, so I welcome any advice. I read that I need to parse the strings to give them an integer value, but I have no idea how to go about doing that.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriviaPart1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Trivia Questions:
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome! Time to begin some trivia");
    //The program pauses for 2 seconds before asking the first question
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    //Question 1
    System.out.println("Who holds the world record for running the fastest 100 meter dash?");

    String questionOne;
    questionOne = scan.nextLine();

    if(questionOne.equalsIgnoreCase("Usain Bolt")) {
        System.out.println("Correct!");
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Incorrect. The answer was: Usain Bolt");
        System.out.println("Next Question");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
    //Question 2
    System.out.println("What is the World's current population?");

    String questionTwo;
    questionTwo = scan.nextLine();

    if(questionTwo.equalsIgnoreCase("7 billion")){
        System.out.println("Correct!");
    }   
    else
        System.out.println("Incorrect. The answer was: 7 billion");
        System.out.println("Next Question");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

        //Question Three
        System.out.println("Why is the sunset blue on Mars?");

        String questionThree;
        questionThree = scan.nextLine();

        if(questionThree.equalsIgnoreCase("Distance from the sun causes the sunlight to lose intensity"))
        {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        }   
        else
            System.out.println("Incorrect. The answer was: Distance from the sun causes the sunlight to lose intensity");
            System.out.println("Next Question");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }

            //Question Four
            System.out.println("What mobile carrier is the most popular in the United States?");

            String questionFour;
            questionFour = scan.nextLine();

            if(questionFour.equalsIgnoreCase("Verizon Wireless")){
                System.out.println("Correct!");
            }

            if(questionFour.equals("Verizon")){
                System.out.println("Correct!");
            }
            else 
                System.out.println("Incorrect. The answer was: Verizon Wireless");
                System.out.println("Next Question");

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }

            //Question Five
            System.out.println("What is the most popular television show today?");

                String questionFive;
                questionFive = scan.nextLine();

            if(questionFive.equalsIgnoreCase("The Big Bang Theory")){
                System.out.println("Correct!");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Incorrect. The answer was: The Big Bang Theory");
                System.out.println("End of Trivia Part 1");

            }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the start of the program, you should declare a variable called `correctCount` like this:

```
int correctCount = 0;
```

And each time the user gets a correct answer, you add 1 to the variable:

```
//Question 1
System.out.println("Who holds the world record for running the fastest 100 meter dash?");

String questionOne;
questionOne = scan.nextLine();

if(questionOne.equalsIgnoreCase("Usain Bolt")) {
    System.out.println("Correct!");
    correctCount++; //here you increase the variable by one.
}
else 
    System.out.println("Incorrect. The answer was: Usain Bolt");
    System.out.println("Next Question");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        }catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
```

Now when the program ends, you display the score like this:

```
System.out.println("Your score: " + correctCount + "/5");
```

Answer (score 0):

I could guide you in this respect but the actual implementation is upto you.You can declare a global variable and get it incremented when the answer is correct
eg:

```
int i=0;
if (answer is correct)
i++
```

After this you can use the value of `i` to display your answer.